# Find the affine transformation between 2 triangles in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, transformation

I have a triangle T and its transformed version T' - i.e, I know the correspondence of vertices between the two triangles.

Is it possible to find the affine transformation A, that transformed T to T'?

I know v1,v2,v3 of T and v1',v2',v3' of T', where each v has a 3D coordinate (x,y,z).

The affine transformation I believe has 12 parameters, so ideally I'd need 4 points to find A. But is there a way to do it with 3 known points (even if approximately)?

Thank you for any ideas..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We assume that the two triangles are non-degenerate.

In fact, in the general case, a linear transform  fulfilling the task. Here is how.

As $A$ must send $V_k$ onto $V'_k$ for $k=1,2,3$, we can write:

$$A \times \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}|&|&|\\V_1&V_2&V_3\\|&|&|\end{pmatrix}}_{B} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}|&|&|\\V'_1&V'_2&V'_3\\|&|&|\end{pmatrix}}_{B'}$$

Two cases :

- The general case : If $\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}$ are independent, matrix $B^{-1}$ exists, and we can take

$$A=B'B^{-1}$$

for the matrix of the transformation.

- If ${V_1,V_2,V_3}$ are dependent (it means that the plane defined by the initial triangle passes through the origin), corresponding matrix $B$ has rank $2$. Then, taking a translation $t$ along the normal vector of this plane, replacing  $\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}$ by $t(\{V_1,V_2,V_3\})$, we are back to the previous case with the existence of a linear transform $\ell$ such that :

$$\ell(t(\{V_1,V_2,V_3\}))=\{V'_1,V'_2,V'_3\}$$

Therefore, composition $a=\ell \circ t$ is a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't always work, for example if $V_1' = [0, 0, 0]$ a linear transformation doesn't exist (and indeed $B$ is not invertible). Is there a more general solution that does work in this case, by actually including a translation?

Comment: @Todd Sewell You address an interesting question ; I am going to attempt to give you a "reasonable" answer.

Comment: You address the case of non invertibility of $B$. Let us consider the case of 2D which is easier to visualize. If $B=[V_1,V_2]$ with $B$ non invertible, it means that one of $V_1,V_2$ is a multiple of the other ; for example $V_1=kV_2$. Then if an affine transform exist mapping the frist traingle onto the second triangle, if the first triangle is flat (which is the case here) the second triangle has to be flat also.

Comment: I think the origin is a special case, you can just translate any non-flat/degenerate triangle such that one of the corners is at the origin. So the invertability of `B` is in this sense unrelated to the degenerateness of the triangle. I guess this is also a solution, just translate away from the origin before this calculation, but I wonder if there's a cleaner solution, maybe using homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: @Todd Sewell "Triggered" by your remarks, I have "cleaned" my answer. You mention homogeneous coordinates ; it could have been a solution, but we don't need it in fact.

Comment: Thanks for the changes! It's still surprising to me that there is this random edge-case to consider, normally linear algebra is a lot "nicer". But translating an arbitrary amount away from the origin does solve the problem nicely.